# How to Build an Executable from Assembly and C Files with Control Flow Integrity Enabled?

Tags: assembly, clang, sanitization, llvm-ir

Is it possible to build an executable from Assembly and C files with Clang's Control Flow Integrity feature enabled?

Generate file `funcs.s` using command:

```
gcc -S funcs.c
```

from `funcs.c` file:

```
int sum(int x, int y) {
  return x + y;
}

int dbl(int x) {
  return x + x;
}

void call_fn(int (*fn)(int)) {
  (*fn)(42);
}

void erase_type(void *fn) {
  call_fn(fn);
}
```

File `main.c`:

```
int main() {
  erase_type(sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Build executable file for the host "x86" platform with enabled "cfi" sanitizer feature:

```
./clang-8 \
-fsanitize=cfi \
-fvisibility=hidden \
-fno-sanitize-trap=all \
-fuse-ld=gold \
-flto \
funcs.s \
main.c \
-o \
main
```

Test feature:

```
./main
```

Problem isn't detected.

P.S. If I use original `funcs.c` file instead of `funcs.s` all works properly:

```
$ ./main 
funcs.c:10:3: runtime error: control flow integrity check for type 'int (int)' failed during indirect function call
(.../build_x86_cfi_lto_asm/main+0x42cb00): note: (unknown) defined here
```

Comment: The common sense suggests that the answer is 'no' (or, at least, not in the way you're producing your asm file). The sanitizer feature is applied to the C code submitted as input to the compiler/linker, any assembly language files are used as-is. You can make a good experiment - get the assembly code from your "correct" object file (by using objdump or whatever is used for this in your dev environment) and compare the result with the assembly you get from your `gcc -S funcs.c`.

Comment: @tum_ I've made an experiment, proposed by you. Yes, funcs.c.o and funcs.s.o are very different. File funcs.c.o is if LLVM IR format ("BC" at the beginning of file). File funcs.s.o is of ELF format. Anyway the question is the same. Is it possible to enable CFI support for Assemble file?

Comment: Try using `gcc -S -fsanitize=cfi funcs.c` to generate the assembly file.

Comment: @RossRidge 
gcc: error: unrecognized argument to -fsanitize= option: ‘cfi’.    gcc version 5.4.0

Comment: Ok, try: `./clang-8 -S -fsanitize=cfi funcs.c`

Comment: @RossRidge They say 'sanitize=cfi' must be accompanied with 'lto'. To OP: you missed the point of the experiment - I suggested to look at the resulting assembly, not the object file content. This would show you what extra code is added by the 'cfi' option, which (the extra code) is obviously missing when you produce the asm by 'gcc -S'.

Comment: @RossRidge I got you! This "./clang-8 -S -fsanitize=cfi -flto -fvisibility=default funcs.c" provides file wtitten in LLVM assembly.

Comment: @RossRidge Generally I agree with tum_ ... Question is in use of file, written in Assembly...

Comment: Note that CFI is a confusing title.  From the question title, I thought it was going to be about hand-written asm with (or missing) directives like `.cfi_def_cfa register, offset` that create *call frame information* `.eh_frame` metadata for stack unwinding.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/CFI-directives.html and  [What do the .eh\_frame and .eh\_frame\_hdr sections store, exactly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14091231).  But in both cases, the answer is: this is stuff that a C compiler can generate while looking at the original C, and can't while just assembling arbitrary asm.